# MySQL where in and find in set both together

Tags: mysql

```
+----+-------+-------------+
| id | ids   | other_data |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 | 1,2,3 | some data  |
|  2 | 1,2   | some data  |
|  3 | 2     | some data  |
|  4 | 6     | some data  |
+----+-------+------------+
```

following command retrieves first and second row and first argument for find_in_set is an integer :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1,ids);
```

What if I want to send multiple ids as first argument? for example something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1,2',ids);
```

I need to retrieve rows containing 1 or 2 in their ids list.

Comment: "What if I want to send multiple ids as first argument?" You need to use `..WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, ids) OR FIND_IN_SET(2, ids)`

Comment: The best solution is to normalize the column id's then you can use the `IN`  clause like so `IN(1, 2)` But you also need to use a JOIN.